# Verify p/invoke statically

Tags: c#, f#, clr, pinvoke, native

Is there a way to statically/against .h-files verify p/invoke so that one doesn't run up against runtime errors like 'a call to a native method unbalanced the stack'?

Preferrably it would be a way that is cross-platform and also work with .so files.

Answer (score 1):

You can reason this out by yourself.  If accurate static analysis were possible then nobody would ever again have to write a [DllImport] declaration, the analysis tool could just auto-generate them.

No such tool exists, C declarations are far too ambiguous.

Your analysis tool cannot work, not without *extra* markup like [SAL annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx) that disambiguates pointers and data flow.  The [Pinvoke Interop Assistant](https://clrinterop.codeplex.com/) uses it for example.  The attributes used in IDL play a very similar role, auto-generating a type library and proxy/stubs in COM.

Comment: Do the SAL annotations work well with Mono? It seems to be a proprietary tech from MSFT? I haven't said that I can't do manual work to correct the signatures: but in my example; the unbalanced stack, it's not about ambigious pointers, but wrong types and/or data structures.

Comment: I added a link to the PInvoke Interop Assistant in your answer. What about runtime verification then - if static verification is impossible as per your answer? FsCheck for p/invoke?

Comment: There's no "tech", they are just empty macros.  The point of course is that somebody has to put them in the declarations first.  Which is rarely done.  Unbalanced stacks are easy to debug, that doesn't need help.  Automatic in .NET with the PInvokeStackImbalance MDA.

Comment: I think you're missing my point about verification, but you have helped me, +1 to that.